# Creating a click event with a addClass/removeClass, click count, and using localStorage to keep user from clicking again later on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage, addclass

Hey I am trying to create a basic like widget that has both a clickable icon and a counter beside it.

The icon will change from empty heart to filled heart on click using addClass/removeClass and the click event is registered and returns a +1 for the click shown as a number beside it.

Here is what I have so far but I am having some trouble:

```
<i id="addButton" onClick="clickME()" class="likeButton fa fa-heart-o"></i>
<p><a id="clicks">0</a></p>

<script>
     var clicks = 0;
    function clickME() {
        clicks += 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
 }
</script>
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wking/ut92yujh/)

The counter works but continued to count after first click.

Secondly the class change I got working here doesn't work.

```
<i class="likeButton fa fa-heart-o"></i>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.likeButton').click(function(){
        $('.likeButton').removeClass('fa-heart-o');
        $(this).addClass('fa-heart');
    });

});
</script>
```

[Heart class change - jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wking/7ku2wwu6/1/)

I tried to look at examples of all of this done seperately and got them close to working but just cannot seem to put it all together. Help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You basically need to toggle the class everytime you click the element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.likeButton').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('fa-heart-o fa-heart');
    });    
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7ku2wwu6/2/

Here's the complete solution :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var clicks = 0;
    $('.likeButton').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('fa-heart-o fa-heart');
        $(this).hasClass("fa-heart") ? clicks++ : clicks-- ;      
        $("#clicks").text(clicks);
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ut92yujh/5/

Comment: That covers the class change bit.

Comment: Yeah that captured exactly what I was looking for with the class change and counter! Now the next step is keeping track of the click so it doesn't reset when the browser reloads and keep track of all visitors that click the icon.

Comment: In that case, you would need to save the current value in a cookie and reload the value from cookie after a page refresh.

Comment: Would you use a cookie or localStorage?